# At which threshold does Autogrow Happen in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2005, database

When a SQL2005 Server's Autogrow is enabled. At which size does this operation take place? Is it triggered on Percentage / Based on statistic's / ...

Is this a thing i can configure? I mean not the Autogrow (Percentage/fixed size)  itself but just when the grow takes place.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. Let me see if I can figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not figure it out myself and since I spend so much time digging around on [Paul Randal's](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/) (SQL MVP) blog I decided to ask him. Here is his response.

> [Autogrow] triggers at 100%, non-configurable. You can roll your own trigger based on an alert and manual growing.

Comment: I know that i can configure the grow. But when does it happen? 
Initial DB Size = 1GB / 20% Grow >> When will it start to grow to 1200 GB? Is it when the DB is filled 80% /800MB or does SQlserver wait untill the 1GB is really full?

Comment: @Paul has always the final say regarding SQL Serer=)

Answer (score 0):

[Autogrow from Micorsoft support site.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315512)